# Sharepoint search api to query documents by term store/set?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a term store which has some terms "Defender", "Forward", etc. I then have a document library which uses those terms as meta data on the documents.

I want to use the sharepoint search api to retrieve any documents that have used the "Defender" meta data, like in the images below.

I have a function to grab the documents:

```
  public getDocuments() {
    axios 
    .get("https://bpk.sharepoint.com/_api/SEARCH DOCUMENTS VIA TERMS FROM THE TERM STORE",
            { params:{},
              headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
            })
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        documents: response.data.d.results
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Can anybody please point me in the right direction for what the search api end point should be? <3

[image]
[image]


SOLUTION:

```
  public getDocuments() {

    axios
      .get("https://bpk.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='owstaxIdPositionx0020:defender'&trimduplicates=true&rowsperpage=100&rowlimit=1000",
        { params:{},
          headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
        })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          documents: response.data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }
```

Comment: site column then no need. if it list column you need to create managed  Property in SharePoint search and then Use the search api  to filter the data 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Comment: I did it yesterday @JayneshSharma my solution has been added to orginal post :)